# How to match dates and text to intersect a value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Hitting a wall a bit here.

I am trying to develop a matrix containing date (on the Y axis) and investment instrument (on the X axis).

Created a pivot and it looks good.

Now I need to extract it from the pivot and match a date with an instrument.

I used the INDEX - MATCH function, but it doesn't work

Any ideas in regards of what the problem might be?

My date format is `yyyy.mm.dd.`

Comment: INDEX(,MATCH(),MATCH()) should work as it is designed to do just that.

Comment: Spits out a #REF!.
Generally, I think that the problem might be in the format of the date.
Also, I am making a reference to another sheet.

Comment: please include some test data expected output and the formula you tried.

Comment: =INDEX(Sheet2!B3:XFD1048576,MATCH(Sheet4!A2,Sheet2!A:A,0),MATCH(Sheet4!B1,Sheet2!B2:DZ2,0))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to help ensure you have a uniform formatting for the date column:

```
ActiveSheet.Columns(9).TextToColumns DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False
```

From there, the index(outputrng, match(searchcell, searchrng, 0)) should work (or index/match/match as suggested by Scott in the comments).

Comment: Thank you Very much, guys!
You have been very helpful! 
Got it sorted!
Special 10x to @ScottCraner